# php str_replace of other functions

Tags: php, string, url-rewriting, str-replace

Im running a mp3 crawler website, I want to remove Get/ from URL because it is causing problem in my seo please have a look of this mp3begins.com,

I tried to use str_replace to remove "/" but no success.

```
$latestitem = $row['term'];
$latestsearch = trim(str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($latestitem)));
$latest_item = stripslashes($latestitem);
$latest_search = stripslashes($latestsearch);
$latestsearch123 = str_replace(" / "," ",$latest_item);
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$latestsearch123 = str_replace("/","",$latest_item);
```

Or are the whitespaces intentional?

Comment: Then I have no idea what you are actually trying to replace.

Answer (score 0):

you could use preg_replace:

```
$yourUrl = "Get/some/Url/you/have";
$trimmedUrl = preg_replace('/Get\\//', '', $yourUrl); 
//result: "some/Url/you/have"
```

Answer (score 0):

`$latestsearch123 = str_replace(" / "," ",$latest_item);` will search for a slash with a space before and a space after. Is that what you intend to do? try it without the spaces.